# Grails Email Plugin Unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, grails

I used the Grails email plugin to send the email in grails project.

However there is no information about how to unit test it in the document.

Are there any idea how to unit test it out?

Thanks.

Comment: [There are some ideas in the documentation of the mail plugin](http://gpc.github.io/grails-mail/docs/guide/4.%20Testing.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the greenmail plugin (http://grails.org/plugin/greenmail). It will receive all the emails sent from the application (once configured) and you can inspect greenmail's 'inbox' from a test.